# How to render thousands of components and not make it laggy when a prop changes in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Starting my React journey and trying to figure out how I can improve rendering of hundreds/thousands of components.

Say you have 3 components - `App`, `ColorPicker`, and `Card`.

```
import { useState } from "react"

function Card({ color }) {
  return (
    <div style={{ backgroundColor: color, height: 300, width: 300, color: '#ffffff' }}>
      {color}
    </div>
  )
}

function ColorPicker({ color, setColor }) {
  return <input type="color" value={color} onChange={(e) => setColor(e.target.value)} />
}

export default function App() {
  const [color, setColor] = useState('#000000')
  const items = [...Array(1000).keys()]

  return (
    <div style={{ display: 'flex', flexWrap: 'wrap', gap: '2rem' }}>
      <ColorPicker color={color} setColor={setColor} />
      { items.map((i) => <Card key={i} color={color}  />) }
    </div>
  )
}
```

When you have like 500 items and you change the color, you think it's good. But if you have like a thousand, you'll notice the lag.

I tried to use third-party libs like [valtio](https://github.com/pmndrs/valtio) and [jotai](https://recoiljs.org/) and still get the same performance.

Is there anything I can improve in this code that will make the rendering smooth?

Comment: Place your state in such a way that you don't need to update thousands of components. This is basically a thought exercise, but you shouldn't need to be rendering thousands of components at once.

Comment: maybe using signals the performance would be better?

Comment: I tried valtio/jotai/recoil and even @preact/signals-react and still get the same performance @Osakr

Comment: Updating 1000 elements seems wrong even without react

Comment: What do you mean by that @Konrad? That it's not ideal to do in general?

Answer (score 3):

When you have 500 items it often means that you are only displaying about 10 or 20 of them. But the browser still renders all those elements. The more elements you have, the more time the browser needs to render your page.

There are multiple ways to tackle this problem (and maybe more):

**1. Let the browser know that it shouldn't render a card element that is outside the visible viewport (your screen) via css (This does not work yet on Safari).**

You will have to specify the height of the card element yourself. Because the browser does not render the element and thus does not calculate the height of the element. In this example I have set the height to 100px:

```css
content-visibility: auto;
contain-intrinsic-size: auto 100px;
```

More info about CSS contain and content-visibility properties:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/content-visibility
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/contain

**2. Remove the card elements that are outside the viewport (your screen) from the html document.**

There are multiple React libraries that can do this for you automatically. It often means that you need to wrap your card elements into some kind of list component of that library.

For example React Virtualized: https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

**3. Or you can do your own optimization on card elements via the Intersection Observer API to detect when an element scrolls outside the viewport**

```js
new IntersectionObserver(
  (entries, observer) => {
    for (const entry of entries) {
      const isOutside = (entry.intersectionRatio === 0);
      if (isOutside) {
        // Optimize the card element
      } else {
        // Restore the card element
      }
    }
  },
  {
    threshold: 0.0001 // Because sometimes a pixel in not visible on screen but the intersectionRatio is already 0
  }
);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API